# What is the name of the process that does the iPhone backup in the background?

Tags: macos, catalina

I am having problems with the iPhone Backup process being hang. What is the name of that process and how can I kill it if I need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Catalina system, the process is `AppleMobileBackup`. If required, you can terminate it using Activity Monitor or `kill` from Terminal, using the process ID.

[image: Process AppleMobileBackup in Acivity Monitor]

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for